# How do I add timeout while using fabric for below code?

Tags: python, invoke, fabric, linux-disk-free

Code is as below. I will explain here.

I use fabric to check the mount point status for 2 server. The command is

```
df -h /mnt
```

The problem of this command is that it may hang there forever, so the fabric code will hang forever.
I think some timeout mechanism will fix this issue. But I did not find it on the fabric doc. Is there any setting about this ?

```
import fabric
from fabric import ThreadingGroup as Group

directory = '/mnt'
group = Group('server1', 'server2', user='someuser', connect_kwargs={'password':'somepassword'})
try:
    result = group.run("df -h %s" % directory)
except fabric.exceptions.GroupException as e:
    err = e
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Option #1:  use bash timeout to stop the command `timeout 10 df -h`

Option #2:  use the `run` function's [`timeout` parameter](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner.run).  timeout is specified in seconds, and a `CommandTimeout` exception is raised if the command times out.

`Group.run`

> Executes `Connection.run` on all member Connections.

[and `Connection.run`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.run)

> wraps an SSH-capable implementation of `invoke.runners.Runner.run`; see its documentation for details.